# Converting $\frac{2}{7}$ to a binary number in a $32$ bit computer

Tags: numerical-methods, binary, computer-arithmetic

I want to convert $\frac{2}{7}$ to a binary number in a $32$ bit computer. That is, $1$ bit is assigned to the sign of the number, $8$ bits are assigned to the exponent, and $23$ bits are assigned to the mantissa.

So $x = \pm q \times 2^{m}$ where $\frac{1}{2} \leq q < 1$ (if $x \neq 0$) and $m = e - 127$ is an integer. Suppose the leading binary digit $1$ is shifted just to the left of the binary point. In this case, the representation would be $q = (1.f)_{2}$ and $1 \leq q < 2$. So in effect, the machine has a $24$-bit mantissa.

The binary representation of $\frac{2}{7}$ is $\left ( 0.010 \overline{010} \right )_{2}$. In normalized notation, this is $ \left ( 0.10\overline{010} \right )_{2} \times 2^{-1}$.

I want to write out fully what this number would like in the $32$ bit computer. So, I should write out $24$ bits for the mantissa.

$$x = \left ( 0.\underbrace{10010010010010010010010}_{23 \text{ bits}}\underbrace{\_}_{24\text{'th bit}} \right )_{2} \times 2^{-1}$$

For the $24th$ bit, do I put a $0$? There is not enough room for the entire $3$-period of $\overline{010}$ so what do I do?

Comment: This is a limitation of floating point variables - there is no "recurring" notation. Also, please note that the normalised mantissa always has a `1` in the most significant place (except for value 0) and in IEEE representations that bit is not stored.

Comment: It depends on the standard of calculation, but ideally you'd round to the nearest 24th digit. Since the "full" digits continue: $01001\dots$, the rounding digit would be $1$, not $0$.

Comment: If you have access to a computer and a programming language, you should be able to access the memory and actually see how it is stored.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, the reason why my work in my post has a $24$-bit mantissa is exactly the reason you stated - that $1$ is not stored. This question stems from an exercise "find the roundoff error" which means check if rounding or chopping the number gives a better approximation to the original binary number. So maybe this unavoidable misrepresentation is intentional by the exercise!

Comment: Also note that IEEE defines [four possible rounding modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html) so this passes the buck to the programmer.

Comment: @WeatherVane I want to check if the rounded number or the chopped number is a more accurate representation on the $32$ bit computer. In my calculations here: http://mathurl.com/yb94zdpv I find that the chopped representation of $x$ is closer to $x$ than $x_{+}$. BUT, I think I am doing the $x_+ - x$ subtraction incorrectly. Otherwise, wouldn't ALL chopped binary numbers be closer to their original number $x$?

Comment: Note that it is possible to build computers (and people actually have built computers) that have 32-bit floating-point numbers that are not encoded in the IEEE-754 format. If you say "IEEE 754" up front then the statements introduced by "that is" or "so" actually _do_ follow from the initial statement.

Comment: There also seems to be a great deal of confusion in the question about how IEEE-754 handles the implicit leading 1 of the mantissa. You seem to be setting yourself up to give the wrong exponent, that is, if you finish writing out your proposed 32-bit encoding of 2/7 you will be off by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no particular reason why your three-period has to be written $010.$
You have multiple choices, depending on where you choose to start looking
for a repeating block.
In particular,
$$ 0.010\overline{010}_2 = 0.01\overline{001}_2 = 0.0\overline{100}_2. $$

And of course even if you did end up with three available bits at the end of the computer word, allowing you to write one copy of your three-period there,
you would still have only an approximation, because all the *other* three-periods (there are infinitely many) don't fit in that space.

So you have to find out how the computer is set up to do rounding of floating-point numbers in this case.
Using the default rule for IEEE-754 binary (round to nearest, ties to even--see the other answer),
you can start to figure out which way to round (up to $1$ or down to $0$)
by looking at the value of the binary digits that don't fit in the
IEEE format.
The least significant bit in the single-precision representation of $\frac27$
has place value $2^{-25},$
and the bits to the right of it have value
$$ 0.10\overline{010} \times 2^{-25}. $$
Since this is greater than $\frac12 \times 2^{-25},$ you round up.
(If it were less, you would round down, and if it were exactly equal you would look at the digit with place value $2^{-25}$ to figure out which way the "round to even" rule goes.)

By the way, notice that the IEEE-754 single-precision representation of
$\frac27,$ as demonstrated in the other answer, has exponent bits
$01111101,$ implying that $$m = e - 127 = 01111101_2 - 127 = -2,$$
not $-1$ as you seem to be assuming when you write,
"$x = \pm q \times 2^{m}$ where $\frac{1}{2} \leq q < 1$ (if $x \neq 0$) and $m = e - 127$ is an integer."

Comment: David, thank you for answer. I had been using an exponent of $-1$ because I thought it would make the binary arithmetic easier, but I think I should have just done $-2$. I also find that $x_-$ is a better approximation to $x$ on the 32 bit computer which means NOT using the rounded number and instead using the chopped number.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how did you decide $x_-$ is a better approximation?

Comment: David, note the problem scope is for a 32 bit computer. To check if the chopped or rounded representation of $x$ is a better approximation, one must compare the absolute errors of $x_-$ and $x_+$. That is, compare the values of $|x - x_{-}|$ and $|x_+ - x|$. Check the amount of error for $x_-$ and $x_+$ then pick the term which is the least amount of it. That term will be the better approximation of $x$.

Comment: @Kazi I didn't mean in general how do you decide, I meant exactly how in this specific case did you decide $x_-$ was better. For $\frac27$ in 32-bit IEEE-754 binary format, $|x_+ - x|=\frac 37\times 2^{-25}$ but $|x - x_-|=\frac 47 \times 2^{-25},$ so by that criterion $x_+$ is the better approximation.

Answer (score 0):

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int a){
	float f = 2.0/7;
	unsigned int i = *(unsigned int*)&f;
	for(a=31;a>=0;a--){
		printf("%d",(i>>a)&1);
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBDsIgFATQNZyC1NhAI7XVhQuEu/xAqT@pYFq6Mj07ws7dZOZlrJytzfmEwS67m9hzSw5j/zIUQ2JvwMBrAPGlxC8REvNMs1s/XB@Kkj1sOIfJsWqwDB3/rzrR@qJ8XDno@6jA6EGBlPWMfNYiPG/OrrlwNAZEO4qiD3rk/AM)

This gives `00111110100100100100100100100101`:

$$\underbrace{\color{blue}{0}}_{+}\underbrace{\color{green}{01111101}}_{2^{125-127}}\underbrace{\color{red}{00100100100100100100101}}_{\times\color{grey}{1.}00100100100100100100101}$$

So, the mantissa is `1.00100100100100100100101` (first `1` implicit).

$$\cdots010010\underline0\color{grey}{10010\cdots} \mapsto \cdots010010\underline1$$

Rounding to the nearest representable number.

---

The [official standard](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/754-1985.html) is behind paywall, so I can only quote a secondary source:

[IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers, Steve Hollasch, 2015 Dec 2](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html):

> Algebraic operations covered by IEEE 754, namely + , - , · , / , √ and Binary <-> Decimal Conversion with rare exceptions, must be *Correctly Rounded* to the precision of the operation’s destination unless the programmer has specified a rounding other than the default. If it does not Overflow, a correctly rounded operation’s error **cannot exceed half the gap between adjacent floating-point numbers** astride the operation’s ideal ( unrounded ) result.

(Emphasis mine.)

A tertiary source:

[IEEE 754, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754):

> The standard defines five rounding rules. [...]
>
> Round to nearest, ties to even – rounds to the **nearest** value; if the number falls midway it is rounded to the nearest value with an even (zero) least significant bit; **this is the default for binary floating-point** and the recommended default for decimal.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Your online code should be `double f = 2.0/7;`

Comment: @ja72 OP is asking 32 bit, i.e. `float`.

Comment: Right. Carry on.